# Intuitive explanation of solution to Laplace's equation on unit disc with boundary conditions (i) $u(1,\theta)=c$, & (ii) $u(1,\theta)=\sin(\theta)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, harmonic-functions

I know it can be explicitly shown that for (i) $u(r,\theta)=c$, and for (ii) $u(r,\theta)=r\sin(\theta)$ by separating variables and finding the Fourier coefficients, but is there any mathematical reasoning behind this without having to tediously compute the coefficients? Again I also know that if the B.C. was $u(1,\theta)=\sin^2(\theta)$, then $u(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2}(1-r^2\cos(2\theta))$. These solutions seem very intuitive and I wonder if it can be argued that these are the solutions without explicit computation of Fourier coefficients?

Also, how can it be shown that in each case the solutions are unique? I.e. for (i) I'm aware that both the real and imaginary parts of an analytic function are harmonic, hence since $f(z)=c$ is analytic then $\text{Re}(f(z))=c$ solves Laplace's equation and satisfies the boundary condition, but how do we know that this is the only solution? This is as far as my background goes on this, I'm not aware of any additional theorems etc.

Comment: solutions are unique if the function is continuous on the unit circle (it is easy to show that if $f=0$ on the unit circle, $P(f)=0$ inside the unit circle, where $P(f)$ is the Poisson transform so the solution to the Laplace equation with boundary condition $f$

Comment: @Conrad  Ok thanks, is there any reasoned argument on why the solutions in these cases seem so intuitive, or is it just a case of having to compute the coefficients in each case?

Comment: not sure about the question - I mean if you are given some equation and you can see a solution by the naked eye so to speak, then if you have unicity (like here), that is *the* solution; if you ask why can you see the solution by "the naked eye" in these cases, I guess that's because they are simple, but not sure if there is any deeper reason